# Counting number of children

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having 2 MySQL table looking something like this:

table parents

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| id    |  name     | birthdate |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|     1 | Mary      | 1974-05-02|
|     2 | John      | 1970-06-03|
|     4 | James     | 1984-07-04|
```

table children

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id    |  parent   | name      |birthdate  |  gender   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     1 | 1         | Sara      |2013-10-22 | female    |
|     2 | 1         | Jack      |2014-05-02 | male      |
|     3 | 1         | Jill      |2015-06-07 | female    |
|     4 | 2         | Sam       |2015-06-07 | male      |
|     5 | 2         | Fred      |2015-06-07 | male      |
|     6 | 3         | Julie     |2015-06-07 | female    |
|     7 | 4         | Megan     |2015-06-07 | female    |
```

How do I retrieve the number of parents (count) that have 3 children?

```
+---------+
|TOTAL    |
+---------+
| 1       |
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `COUNT` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM parents p
INNER JOIN children c
    ON c.parent = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 3
```

---

To get the number of `parent`s with 3 `children`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM parents p
    INNER JOIN children c
        ON c.parent = p.id
    GROUP BY p.id
    HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 3
) t
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to get the total number of parents in just one query? Your answer gives me each partent id that have 3 children.

Comment: Perfect! This is it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see following way:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id) as TOTAL
FROM parents as p
INNER JOIN children as c
    ON c.parent = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 3
```

Comment: Hi. This was the output I was getting and didn't work for me because I needed just the total. Thanks